# Yii save multiple models into a 3rd connecting table with validation

Tags: validation, model, yii, save, multiple-instances

I have 2 tables: `Order(s)` and `Product(s)`. And I have a 3rd one that connects them: `OrdersProducts`. I would like to save several models at once into `OrdersProducts` like so:

I would like to select one single Order `nr`, and from a `grid,` select several `products`, `adjust amounts` and then save all.

My problem is, that I can't make it to show to the user in an appropriate manner if there is a validation error.

The best would be, to show it right there on the form, but I have no clue how to include the 3rd model into the form. I already have the `form`, and I can save several (or multiple) models at once, but if there is an error, for example: `an amount is missing`, I don't know how to tell it to the user.

Right now the save is finished, except the ones with errors, but this way the user would have to check all the time if all rows managed to be saved, what would be a nonsense.

The best would be to show the user right there on the form, highlight the problematic row in the grid (or any other way show that there is a problem with this or that particular row or *field*)

Does it make any sense? If yes, what can be a good (and simple...?) solution for this?

Thanks a lot!
BR
c

Comment: How are you showing the inputs? Can you show some of the code?

Comment: it's a simple dropdown on the top for Orders, and a simple grid widget extended with checkboxes and textfields based on this article: http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/353/working-with-cgridview-in-admin-panel/

Comment: I guess it would be somehow necessary to create as many models for OrdersProducts, as many rows are filtered in the grid. But I don't have yet any clues how to do it, but I keep searching in the meanwhile.

Comment: IT WORKS! I've managed to figure it out how to make it. It's a little bit tricky and not a very elegant solution, but it basically works as I expect it. Only a few small flaws left to polish. http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/44002-multiple-model-save/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IT WORKS! I've managed to figure it out how to make it. It's a little bit tricky and not a very elegant solution, but it basically works as I expect it. Only a few small flaws left to polish. http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/44002-multiple-model-save/
If anybody finds any mistakes in the theory, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

It took reading this a couple times before I realized what you are doing.  This is a basic order entry problem.  Typically this is solved by creating the order, and then creating the order details one by one. You can show them on the grid as they are created. The thing that confused me was that you seem to have a bunch of empty orders already created, and are trying to do some sort of many to many assignment of products to the orders.  That is complicating things far too much.

Better to:

1. Create a new order.  This can be when the user selects the first item to put into a shopping cart, or simply by initiating a create order screen which populates the order header information.
2. Add an item to the newly created order.  Once again this can be that first item added to the shopping cart, or you can just click a button to bring up a create form that simply adds a single item to the order.  As each product is added, you can perform your validations for that product.
3. Repeat step 2 until all products are added to the order.

The create form can be embedded into the page with the grid view and header attributes, and can be posted using an ajax process to allow the grid to be updated for each product added to the order, or it can be a discrete form on a separate page, or it can be a thing where you return to a product page and select the next product like a shopping cart.  But in each case you are only adding and validating a single product at a time.  That many to many selection thing really only works well for a configuration scenario where you have a small number of values to select from and the only validation necessary is that a selection is required or not.

Comment: yes, maybe the example is not the best, because can be misleading a little bit, but it works like so. Better to imagine Trucks and Products. You have to start several Trucks ahead, but (let's just suppose) you don't know exactly which will arrive first to be loaded with Products. So you will have a many-many relationship, because there will be same products on different Trucks, and Trucks will carry different Products.
Sorry but I don't really see now the point of your suggestion. The user wants to filter in a grid, and associate a certain Truck to several products, at once.

Comment: I see now what you mean. I have already done it to do it one by one, but unfortunately it's not allowed to add Products one by one. It would be too complicated for the user.

Comment: Do you know which products go together on a shipment ahead of time, just not which truck will take them? Or are you putting a random set of products on each truck, and you record each as it is loaded.  Do you have multiple shipments per truck going to different places or do you have a single shipment per truck.  How do you know what to put on each truck?  I am trying to determine if you need to key the orders - let me call then Bills of Ladding (BOL) since we are talking about trucking - ahead of time or if you have to key them just before or while the truck is being loaded.

Comment: the point is, the Trucks are existing, and Products also. I decide which Truck loads which product in the last minute, when a random Truck arrives, and depending on how much and what kind of free loading capacity it has, I load different Products on them. In the meanwhile I could somewhat do something but I'm stuck now: http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/44002-multiple-model-save

Comment: Maybe this will help http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/form.table. It references only a single model, but maybe you could adjust it to use two models.

Comment: yes, I began working based on this guide article, and I'm very close now to the final solution (well, it's not a real solution, but the whole thing will behave totally like it should), but there are still a few flaws, please have a look at his thread: http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/44002-multiple-model-save/page__view__findpost__p__211674 thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Use a [CFormModel](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/form.model) to validate the data entered by the user. Add a function to your form model which validates the data and then stores the data in different models. To capture unforeseen errors at the database level you should use [transactions](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/database.dao#using-transactions%22transactions%22).